# Swedish Noun Gender List

Tags: data-request, language, corpora, dictionary

I'm looking for a lexical resource on Swedish noun genders.

In my case which nouns that have gender neuter or not, that is if the indefinite article is `en` or `ett`.

Comment: You stumped my google-fu. You could mass download/find a corpus of Swedish webpages and create this yourself, but that would be project level work.

Comment: https://sv.wiktionary.org/ may also be helpful

Comment: Try [SAOL for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=se.svenskaakademien.saol&hl=sv). The `.obb` file is a regular SQLite database.

Comment: folks - these should be answers - not comments!

Comment: @StanislavKralin - here's a link to the OBB file http://apk-dl.com/saol

Answer (score 5):

Probably the [Swedish Academian Wordlist](https://svenska.se/om/om-ordbockerna/) (SAOL) is the most authoritative source in this field.
There exists [SAOL for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=se.svenskaakademien.saol), the `.obb` expansion file is a regular SQLite database.

[**This list**](https://nofile.io/f/ajsofUO6a6C/list.tsv.zip) was extracted from the .obb database file. The list contains more than 90 000 nouns (whereas the list from dict.cc contains less than 9 000 nouns). About 75% of nouns are en-words.

If there is a second norm for a particular noun (e. g for *acetylen*), the third column contains '1'.  However, homonyms with different genders (e.g. *val*) are separate records.

```
glimmer         en  
glimmer         ett 
glimmermineral  ett  1
```

---

---

This is how SAOL article looks like.

[image]

All content is stored in the single `saol` table. This table is rather an additional markup level, data is not very structured.

```
SELECT * FROM saol WHERE article = 5 ORDER BY rowid;
```

```
+---------+------+------------------------------------------------------+
| article | code |                         data                         |
+---------+------+------------------------------------------------------+
|       5 |   31 | abakus                                               |
|       5 |  151 | lnr435725                                            |
|       5 |   24 | abak·­us                                              |
|       5 |   43 | [ab´ak‑<span class=pt> el.</span> ab`ak‑]             |
|       5 |    2 | substantiv                                           |
|       5 |   17 | ~en ~er                                              |
|       5 |  161 |                                                      |
|       5 |   38 | •                                                    |
|       5 |  163 | xnr435726                                            |
|       5 |   19 | kul­ram <span class=pt>t.ex. i Kina och Japan</span>  |
|       5 |  164 | 154                                                  |
|       5 |  162 | 152                                                  |
|       5 |  171 | bojning435725                                        |
|       5 |  101 | <i>Singular</i>                                      |
|       5 |  102 | <i>en</i> <b><span class=bform>abakus</span></b>     |
|       5 |  103 | obestämd form                                        |
|       5 |  102 | <i>en</i> <b><span class=bform>abakus</span></b>     |
|       5 |  103 | obestämd form genitiv                                |
|       5 |  102 | <b><span class=bform>abakusen</span></b>             |
|       5 |  103 | bestämd form                                         |
|       5 |  102 | <b><span class=bform>abakusens</span></b>            |
|       5 |  103 | bestämd form genitiv                                 |
|       5 |  101 | <i>Plural</i>                                        |
|       5 |  102 | <b><span class=bform>abakuser</span></b>             |
|       5 |  103 | obestämd form                                        |
|       5 |  102 | <b><span class=bform>abakusers</span></b>            |
|       5 |  103 | obestämd form genitiv                                |
|       5 |  102 | <b><span class=bform>abakuserna</span></b>           |
|       5 |  103 | bestämd form                                         |
|       5 |  102 | <b><span class=bform>abakusernas</span></b>          |
|       5 |  103 | bestämd form genitiv                                 |
+---------+------+------------------------------------------------------+
```

Basically, you just need to retrieve first record with `code` equal to `102` for each `article` that has a record with `code` equal to `2` and `data` equal to `substantiv` , `oböjligt substantiv` etc.

```
SELECT a.data
FROM saol a LEFT JOIN saol b ON a.article = b.article
WHERE a.code = 102 AND b.code = 2 AND b.data LIKE '%substantiv%'
GROUP BY a.article HAVING MIN(a.rowid)
```

However, there are many words that break this logic (e.g., *val* and *abstrakt*; please look into their cards). [**This fiddle**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xjJGqmFVMeM14YdtrfjWsr/2) explains how to deal with such words and how to create the list I have linked to.

Essentially, one should restore 'declension tables' in articles, then get first row from each table, if this table is not for adjective, and then parse this row and strip HTML.

Answer (score 2):

[dict.cc](https://www.dict.cc/) has downloadable dictionaries

https://www1.dict.cc/translation_file_request.php?l=e

You can choose either English (EN) to Swedish (SV) or from German (DE) to SV, and the opposite direction. Email address is required to receive download links.

The file is tab-separated, and each noun (is labeled as u, n or pl)

```
öl {u}  beer    noun
örhänge {n} earring noun
örter {pl}  herbs   noun
```

---

The license:

> PERSONAL USE: Utilizing the data for personal use is granted provided that the data is not given away to third parties or published in any way.
>
> UTILIZATION WITHIN COMPUTER PROGRAMS: Using the data within computer programs is permitted, as long as the following terms are observed:
> Programs using data of dict.cc must be subject to the terms of the GPL.
> This means, amongst other rules, that the source code of the program must be made available to the public.
>
> The data itself must not be published with the program. The user must be asked to download the data directly from dict.cc. This will ensure that every user has seen and agreed to these Terms of Use.
> The program must not be intended or suitable for publishing the data on the Internet, not even partially.

---

*I used this dictionary for the [German Noun Ending dataviz](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/35729/2732)*:

[image]